# SQL Server query optimization date calculations

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find a more efficient way of re-writing my query.

Any suggestions? I am currently also thinking of displaying the fiscal month name as a number itself, then to compare and return month name.

```
(case                                   --proj_end_fis_mon
    when (MYMW.mfg_year_no = FYQM.fiscal_year_no and MYMW.mfg_month_no = 12)
    then                    
        (convert(varchar,(MYMW.mfg_year_no-1))+'-'+(case
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Jan%' then '01'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Feb%' then '02'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Mar%' then '03'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Apr%' then '04'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'May' then '05'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'June' then '06'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'July' then '07'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Aug%' then '08'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Sep%' then '09'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Oct%' then '10'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Nov%' then '11'
            when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Dec%' then '12'
            end))
    else
    (convert(varchar,MYMW.mfg_year_no)+'-'+(case
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Jan%' then '01'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Feb%' then '02'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Mar%' then '03'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Apr%' then '04'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'May' then '05'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'June' then '06'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'July' then '07'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Aug%' then '08'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Sep%' then '09'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Oct%' then '10'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Nov%' then '11'
    when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Dec%' then '12'
    end))


    end)
```

This is what my tables look like:

[image]

Comment: Why the lengthy `case when FM.fiscal_month_name like 'Jan%' then '01' when ... end` and not just `FM.fiscal_month_no` ?

Comment: +1 yes. that be a better way. Just going to convert that num into varchar. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the fiscal month *number* available:

```
Convert( VarChar(4), MYMW.mfg_year_no -
    case when MYMW.mfg_year_no = FYQM.fiscal_year_no and MYMW.mfg_month_no = 12 then 1
      else 0 end ) +
    '-' + Right('0' + Convert( VarChar(2), FM.fiscal_month_no ), 2 )
```

Comment: +1 This works great for me.
Thanks.
Can you please also explain the logic behind it in simpler 'english' terms. :)

Comment: @camelbrush - The first part `convert`s the manufacturing year from an integer to a string.  Tucked inside it is the `case` that subtracts one from the year if your specified condition matches, otherwise it subtracts zero.  That takes care of the only difference (Pardon the pun.) you had between the first and second halves of your sample code.  The last line concatenates the dash and then handles the month.  The month number is `convert`ed from an integer to a string.  Since it might be one or two digits, an zero is tacked on the left side and then the `right` two characters are taken.